# How to use less memory with this function?

Tags: c#, image-processing, unsafe

I am extracting info from about 70,000 images and wanted to get their average RGB info. The current code below works, but runs out of memory. So far it just prints out the camera make, model, RGB values and file name. To get started, I found this code, which I adapted:

```
    public static RGBValues AverageRGB(Bitmap bm)
    {
        BitmapData srcData = bm.LockBits(
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        int stride = srcData.Stride;

        IntPtr Scan0 = srcData.Scan0;

        long[] totals = new long[] { 0, 0, 0 };

        int width = bm.Width;
        int height = bm.Height;

        unsafe
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    for (int color = 0; color < 3; color++)
                    {
                        int idx = (y * stride) + x * 4 + color;

                        totals[color] += p[idx];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        long avgB = totals[0] / (width * height);
        long avgG = totals[1] / (width * height);
        long avgR = totals[2] / (width * height);
        RGBValues rgb = new RGBValues();
        rgb.R = avgR;
        rgb.G = avgG;
        rgb.B = avgB;
        return rgb;
    }

    public class RGBValues
    {
        public long R;
        public long G;
        public long B;
    }
```

I then call it like this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        string folder = @"F:\Photos";
        DirSearch(folder);
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var filename in filelist)
        {
            GetImageInfo(filename);
            counter++;
            if (counter >= 10)
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                counter = 0;
            }
        }

        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void GetImageInfo(string filename)
    {
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(filename);

        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(filename);
        PropertyItem[] propItems = bmp.PropertyItems;
        var temp = AverageRGB(bmp);
        string manufacturer = encoding.GetString(propItems[1].Value);
        string model = encoding.GetString(propItems[2].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("manufacturer: " + manufacturer + ", model: " + model + ", colorinfo: " + temp.R + ", " + temp.G + ", " + temp.B + ", Filename: " + info.Name);
    }
    public static void DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                {
                    filelist.Add(f);
                }
                DirSearch(d);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

I threw in some garbage collection efforts, but it still runs out of memory after doing around 150 photos. I thought that C# would automatically discard info it didn't need anymore. Is it because this is using `unsafe` that it continues to hold on to extra info? What can I do to force it to purge old info?

Comment: Everything which implements a `Dispose` method ought to be disposed of when you are done with it (always).  That `bitmap` for instance.  It wont make it use less, but it will reduce the amount the app leaks resources

Comment: Dispose, dispose, dispose. Put `bitmap` in a `using` block

Comment: Add `UnlockBits`

Comment: @harold I don't believe `UnlockBits` does anything other than copy the bits back. I don't think it's necessary, all that needs to happen is the bitmap is disposed

Comment: @Charlieface Maybe? The documentation doesn't really say anything about what it really means for the data to be "locked in system memory". On the other hand, lack of dispose won't *leak* bitmaps, disposing is a shotcut for early finalization.

Comment: Lack of `Dispose` can very much leak, because it requires two rounds of GC with finalizers running in between. A memory allocation probably will not wait for that to finish before throwing. But I think you are right, `LockBits` without an input buffer means GDI+ will allocate it and it needs de-allocation

Comment: @Charlieface needing two rounds is not a leak, just a delay. I agree that hypothetically it could lead to exceptions, but could it in OPs program which added explicit GCs after every image?

Comment: Thanks guys, I am new to `Dispose` and `Lockbits` but just got back and will give it a try after some research.

Comment: @harold `UnlockBits` was the answer, so simple, but I wouldn't have found it without help. The full line of code is: `bm.UnlockBits(srcData);` after the unsafe block closes. Only using 200MB RAM now instead of 4GB.